# Passing variables/parameters from one Ruby class to a loaded Ruby program

Tags: ruby, class, parameter-passing

The below combined programs should ask for a number remove the first digit (lets call this new number x) and then compute x % 7. Ex: (1121546 % 7) = 5

This all appears to be working except that the number entered in will always compute to 0. modulo_7.rb works by itself and will print the correct outcome when passed a parameter.

The question is am I not passing the variables/ parameters properly or is there something else that is getting in the way?

```
class Number_check_interface
    def get_cert_number
        print "You are about to check receive the check number for a policy/cert id."
        @cert_id = nil
        until @cert_id.is_a?(Fixnum) do             
            puts " Enter the policy/cert ID. "  
            begin                               
                   @cert_id = Integer(gets)           
               rescue ArgumentError                
            end
        end         
    end
end

class Run_number_check_interface

    def run
        load 'modulo_7.rb'
        n = Number_check_interface.new                                 
        n.get_cert_number                                              

        checking_policy_number = Get_policy_check_digit.new(@cert_id)  
        checking_policy_number.create_check_digit
    end
end

run = Run_number_check_interface.new
run.run
```

---

modulo_7.rb

This program removes the first digit (index 0) of a 7 digit number and returns the difference 7%18 is 4 since 4 is remainder of how many times 7 can fit into 18.

```
class Get_policy_check_digit
    def initialize(cert_id)
        #instance variable
        @cert = cert_id
    end

    def create_check_digit
        cert_id_6 = @cert.to_s
        cert_id_6.slice!(0)

        puts cert_id_6
        check_digit = cert_id_6.to_i % 7
        puts "Your check digit is #{check_digit}"
    end
end

# n = Get_policy_check_digit.new(1121546) When uncommented this will create a new instance
                                         # of Get_policy_check_digit with the parameter 1121546
# n.create_check_digit                    This will run the method create_check_digit with the
                                         # parameter 1121546
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instance variables are scoped to an individual instance of a class. So when you say `@cert_id = Integer(gets)` inside `Number_check_interface`, you are only setting `@cert_id` for that particular instance of `Number_check_interface`. Then, when you later write `Get_policy_check_digit.new(@cert_id)` inside `Run_number_check_interface`, you are referring to an entirely different `@cert_id`, one which is specific to that particular instance of `Run_number_check_interface`, and not to the `Number_check_interface` you stored in `n` earlier.

The simple solution is to return `@cert_id` from `Number_check_interface#get_cert_number`, and then pass the returned value to `Get_policy_check_digit.new`:

```
class Number_check_interface
    def get_cert_number
        print "You are about to check receive the check number for a policy/cert id."
        @cert_id = nil # This is an instance variable. It's only accessible
                       # from inside this instance of `Number_check_interface`
        until @cert_id.is_a?(Fixnum) do             
            puts " Enter the policy/cert ID. "  
            begin                               
                   @cert_id = Integer(gets)          
               rescue ArgumentError                
            end
        end
        return @cert_id # Return the contents of @cert_id
    end
end


class Run_number_check_interface

    def run
        load 'modulo_7.rb'
        n = Number_check_interface.new
        cert_number = n.get_cert_number # Here we call `get_cert_number` and
                                        # set `cert_number` to it's return
                                        # value.

        # Notice how we use `cert_number` here:
        checking_policy_number = Get_policy_check_digit.new(cert_number)
        checking_policy_number.create_check_digit
    end
end
```

Other tips:

- Convention in Ruby is to [name classes with CamelCase](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#camelcase-classes).
- Require dependencies at the top of your files, not in the middle of method calls.
- Unless you have a very good reason not to, use `require`, not `load`
- You might want to think a bit harder about what purpose these classes serve, and what behavior they are intending to encapsulate. The API seems a bit awkward to me right now. Remember, tell, don't ask.

Comment: I see that cert_number is equal to n.get_cert_number and that is is passed to Get_policy_check_digit. "cert_number" is a representation of Number_check_interface.get_cert_number. It appears to me that what is being passed is more than a simple variable. How does this work by passing that?

Comment: @Nick It really is just a simple variable. `cert_number` is getting set to whatever `n.get_cert_number` returns, which in this case should be the integer the user entered. Note that I changed the function above to _return_ `@cert_id`. I'll annotate my code to make it more clear what I changed.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. One last thing. The line cert_number = n.get_cert_number also executes n.get_cert_number as far as I can tell. I was under the impression I would have to state after that line cert_number by itself. Would doing that just be redundant?

Comment: @Nick You mean add another line after `cert_number = n.get_cert_number` that just says `cert_number`? What gave you the impression that would be necessary? `cert_number` is just a variable, a line like that would do nothing. Were confused by the way `cert_id` was returned from `get_cert_number` in the other answer?

Comment: I thought I saw some things being coded that way in different examples but not yours. When I comment out the last coded lines of the  `Run_number_check_interface` method up to `cert_number = n.get_cert_number` the `get_cert_number` method would not execute. What I think is happening is that line is responsible for it executing which I did not understand why it would. Others I understand how the code is being works.

Comment: @Nick `get_cert_number` executes on the line that contains `n.get_cert_number`. Nothing in the `run` method after that line should be necessary for `get_cert_number` to be called.

Answer (score 0):

Why are these separate classes?  The design here seems strange, is this ported from another language?  It's more complicated than it needs to be.  Without changing your structure, here's what's wrong:

In `Run_number_check_interface` you are reading `@cert_id`, it doesn't have an instance variable named that, but `Number_check_interface` does.  Just return it from `get_cert_number`:

```
class Number_check_interface
  def get_cert_number
    print "You are about to check receive the check number for a policy/cert id."
    cert_id = nil
    until cert_id.is_a?(Fixnum) do             
      puts " Enter the policy/cert ID. "  
      begin                               
        cert_id = Integer(gets)           
      rescue ArgumentError                
      end
    end
    cert_id     # <-- returing the value here
  end
end

class Run_number_check_interface
  def run
    load 'modulo_7.rb'
    n = Number_check_interface.new                                 
    cert_id = n.get_cert_number                                   # <-- saving here

    checking_policy_number = Get_policy_check_digit.new(cert_id)  # <-- no longer an ivar
    checking_policy_number.create_check_digit
  end
end

run = Run_number_check_interface.new
run.run
```

Comment: I'm new to the language and I am converting old programs over to Ruby. I am told that some of the programs need to be separate but still need to be able to work together.

Comment: You returned cert_id without keying it as: return cert_id. Is it optional to use return that way?

Comment: Yup. The value of a method is its last expression, so that works.